# Take prefix slice of &str that matches `Pattern` in rust

Tags: string, rust, pattern-matching, slice

My ultimate goal is to parse the prefix number of a `&str` if there is one. So I want a function that given `"123abc345"` will give me a pair `(u32, &str)` which is `(123, "abc345")`.

My idea is that if I have a [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html) type I should be able to do something like

```rust
/// `None` if there is no prefix in `s` that matches `p`,
/// Otherwise a pair of the longest matching prefix and the rest
/// of the string `s`.
fn split_prefix<P:Pattern<'a>(s: &'a str, p: P) -> Option<(&'a str, &'a str)>;
```

My goal would be achieved by doing something like

```
let num = if let Some((num_s, rest)) = split_prefix(s, char::is_digit) {
  s = rest;
  num_s.parse()
}
```

What's the best way to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source for [`str::split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once) and modified slightly to inclusively return a greedily matched prefix.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe50f4ee7e1e5227cccaf3c94e7bf2ee)

```rust
#![feature(pattern)]
use std::str::pattern::{Pattern, Searcher};

/// See source code for `std::str::split_once`
fn split_prefix<'a, P: Pattern<'a>>(s: &'a str, p: P) -> Option<(&'a str, &'a str)> {
    let (start, _) = p.into_searcher(s).next_reject()?;
    // `start` here is the start of the unmatched (rejected) substring, so that is our sole delimiting index
    unsafe { Some((s.get_unchecked(..start), s.get_unchecked(start..))) }                                    

    // If constrained to strictly safe rust code, an alternative is:
    // s.get(..start).zip(s.get(start..))
}
```

This generic prefix splitter could then be wrapped in a specialized function to parse out numerical prefixes:

```rust
fn parse_numeric_prefix<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Option<(u32, &'a str)> {                                             
    split_prefix(s, char::is_numeric)
        .map(|(num_s, rest)| num_s.parse().ok().zip(Some(rest)))
        .flatten()
}
```

UPDATE:
I just re-read your question and realized you want a `None` when there is no prefix match. Updated functions:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d71e09194cd86960a478fba494236a9)

```rust
fn split_prefix<'a, P: Pattern<'a>>(s: &'a str, p: P) -> Option<(&'a str, &'a str)> {
    let (start, _) = p.into_searcher(s).next_reject()?;
    if start == 0 {
        None
    } else {
        unsafe { Some((s.get_unchecked(..start), s.get_unchecked(start..))) }
    }
}

fn parse_numeric_prefix<'a>(s: &'a str) -> Option<(u32, &'a str)> {                                             
    split_prefix(s, char::is_numeric)
        // We can unwrap the bare `Result` now since we know there's a
        // matched numeric which will parse
        .map(|(num_s, rest)| (num_s.parse().unwrap(), rest))
}
```